# Выборка из Mysql с помощью JOIN

Tags: база-данных, php, html, mysql

Есть таблица `members`, в ней столбцы (id, name) и таблица `mail`, в ней столбцы (UserTo, UserFrom, Message); при отправке сообщения пользователь пользователю в таблицу `mail` забивается id юзера. Например: (от кого) UserTo=1, (кому) UserFrom=2, (сообщение) Message=текст.

Вопрос: как привязать id имя пользователя, чтобы не выводился id на страницу, а выводилось имя. Мне тут подсказали, что примерно так:

```
mysql_query("select mail.Message, members.name from mail inner join members on members.userid=mail.userid");
```

Но как это все реализовать на странице, я и понятия не имею. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно подсказали... Только запрос не совсем правильный (судя по описанию ваших табличек).

```
mysql_query("select mail.Message, members.name from mail inner join members on members.id=mail.UserTo(или UserFrom в зависимости от задачи)");
```

В результате запроса, mysql вернет строчки с двумя столбцами в каждой. Это Message и name.

Answer (score 0):

> Но как это все реализовать на
> странице, я и понятия не имею. :(

тогда может стоит вернуться к основам и почитать чтото про php и sql?))
ато напихаете кода как попало, а как работает оно не разберетесь.. Советую поупражнятся на более простых примерах